# Extracting each sample type and aliquot number for each ID

Tags: r, database, data-structures

I have this dataset below, I need to keep one row per sample type per ID, but need to keep the max aliquot number so not just keeping first instance.

**Original data -**

```
structure(list(ID = c("0226", "0226", "0226", "0226", "0226", 
"0226", "0226", "0226", "0226", "0226", "0226", "0226", "0226", 
"0226", "0226", "0226", "0226", "0226", "0053", "0053", "0053", 
"0053", "0053", "0053", "0053", "0053", "0053", "0053", "0053", 
"0053", "0053", "0053", "0053", "0053", "0053", "0053", "0053", 
"0053"), `Unique Aliquot ID` = c("C0226BCV1S 01", "C0226BCV1S 02", 
"C0226BCV1S 03", "C0226BCV1S 04", "C0226BCV1S 05", "C0226BCV1S 06", 
"C0226BCV1S 07", "C0226BCV1B 01", "C0226BCV1B 02", "C0226BCV1E 01", 
"C0226BCV1E 02", "C0226BCV1E 03", "C0226BCV1E 04", "C0226BCV1E 05", 
"C0226BCV1E 06", "C0226BCV1N 01", "C0226BCV1N 02", "C0226BCV1N 03", 
"C0053BCV1S 01", "C0053BCV1S 02", "C0053BCV1S 03", "C0053BCV1S 04", 
"C0053BCV1S 05", "C0053BCV1S 06", "C0053BCV1S 07", "C0053BCV1S 08", 
"C0053BCV1B 01", "C0053BCV1B 02", "C0053BCV1E 01", "C0053BCV1E 02", 
"C0053BCV1E 03", "C0053BCV1E 04", "C0053BCV1E 05", "C0053BCV1E 06", 
"C0053BCV1E 07", "C0053BCV1N 01", "C0053BCV1N 02", "C0053BCV1N 03"
), `sample type` = c("S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "B", 
"B", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "N", "N", "N", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "B", "B", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "N", "N", "N"), `Aliquot Number` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -38L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Intended Dataset -**

```
structure(list(ID = c("0226", "0226", "0226", "0226", "0053", 
"0053", "0053", "0053"), `Unique Aliquot ID` = c("C0226BCV1S 07", 
"C0226BCV1B 02", "C0226BCV1E 06", "C0226BCV1N 03", "C0053BCV1S 07", 
"C0053BCV1B 02", "C0053BCV1E 07", "C0053BCV1N 03"), `sample type` = c("S", 
"B", "E", "N", "S", "B", "E", "N"), `Aliquot Number` = c(7, 2, 
6, 3, 7, 2, 7, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Please help

Comment: I'm not sure how you get your intended dataset because you have aliquot number of 8 in your input that does not appear in your output.  That said, `d %>% group_by(ID, ``sample type``) %>% slice_max(``Aliquot Number``)` (where `d` is your input data frame) should be tidyverse solution to your problem.  But, oh, those column names are a pain! (especially when trying to format my code.  Work out the back ticks for yourself...)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[!is.na(`Aliquot Number`), 
              .SD[which.max(`Aliquot Number`)], 
              by = .(ID, `sample type`)]

     ID sample type Unique Aliquot ID Aliquot Number
1: 0226           S     C0226BCV1S 07              7
2: 0226           B     C0226BCV1B 02              2
3: 0226           E     C0226BCV1E 06              6
4: 0226           N     C0226BCV1N 03              3
5: 0053           S     C0053BCV1S 08              8
6: 0053           B     C0053BCV1B 02              2
7: 0053           E     C0053BCV1E 07              7
8: 0053           N     C0053BCV1N 03              3
```